# How can I find the length to this geometry problem?

Tags: geometry

A person 6 feet tall is standing at the base of a lamp post that is 25 feet tall and then begins to walk away from the lamp post. When the person is 10 feet from the lamp post, what is the length  of the person's shadow? Round to the nearest tenth of a foot.

Comment: First thing you should always do in a problem like this: Draw a picture, with all lengths you've been given written in wherever they fit.

Comment: Draw a picture and note the similar triangles.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Now look at the similar triangles. *P* is to *S* what *L* is to *S+X*

Answer (score 1):

Solve for x following equation :

$25 : (10+x) = 6 : x$

Comment: If you want to know where this solution came from, draw a diagram and consider like-triangles.

Comment: @nathan.j.mcdougall Thanks for comment .

Answer (score 0):

Let x be the length of shadow. Using similar triangles, the ratios of side lengths are equal. So 6/x = 25/(x+10).

This gives 6x+60=25x, so 19x=60, so x=3.2.

Answer (score 0):

Draw a right angled triangle. The common apex  say A, of the two triangles whose  lengths are x and 6 (side and hypotenuse) has angle   $\theta$. By similar triangles proportioning:

$$ \tan \theta  = \frac {6}{x} = \frac {25} {x+10}, $$

$$ 6 \, x + 60 = 25 \, x,$$

$$  x = \frac {60}{19} \rightarrow  x  = 3. 16 \, feet.$$